# Setting newString in isPartialStringValid from Swift

Tags: swift

NSFormatter's [isPartialStringValid:newEditingString:errorDescription:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFormatter/isPartialStringValid:newEditingString:errorDescription:) has two output parameters declared as `NSString **` in Objective-C, and `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>` in Swift. I have implemented the following formatter in an NSFormatter subclass and attached it to an NSTextField:

```
override func isPartialStringValid(partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>) -> Bool {
    if count(partialString) > count(hostnamePlaceholder) {
        return false
    } else if count(partialString) > 0 {
        let extendedString: String
        if count(partialString) < count(hostnamePlaceholder) {
            let substring = hostnamePlaceholder.substringFromIndex(advance(hostnamePlaceholder.startIndex, count(partialString)))
            extendedString = partialString + substring
        } else {
            extendedString = partialString
        }
        if hostnamePattern.numberOfMatchesInString(extendedString, options: NSMatchingOptions(0), range: NSMakeRange(0, count(hostnamePlaceholder))) != 1 {
            return false
        }
    }
    // As long as I don't try to set newString it works.
    //newString.memory = partialString.uppercaseString
    return true
}
```

It successfully verifies input as intended and won't let me enter invalid characters. However, I would like to force upper case input but when I set newString the application crashes in objc_release as soon as the method returns. What am I missing? I'm using Xcode 6.3 beta 1.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there is a bug in String.uppercaseString in Swift 1.2b1: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1102105#1102105

With `newstring.memory = partialString` it doesn't crash.